# 5 Beeps; Is it a Hardware Breakdown?

Tags: hardware-failure, defective-hardware

My PC shows up an OC fail error everytime I start it up and i used to continue to Windows without actually looking for the error. Today, it has stopped working, it boots up and then on a blank screen stops and starts beeping with 5 sets of sounds. What is the problem with it?

HP Compaq dx2280 MT,
Award Modular BIOS v6.00PG,
Intel 945 AGPSet BIOS for 8I945GM-RH-HP V1.07

Comment: You also need to indicate the beep sequence - each beep is typically either short or long, and the sequences can have different meanings. With that said, 5 beeps is almost always a CPU failure.

Comment: What do you mean by "OC fail error"? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [service manua](https://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=3310266&docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c00816199)l 5 beeps indicates a memory issue.

They describe two very similar failure scenarios, with some basic troubleshooting tips:

> Blank screen and the power LED flashes Red five times, once every
>   second, followed by a two second pause, and the computer beeps five
>   times. (Beeps stop after fifth iteration but LEDs continue flashing.)
>   Cause Solution Pre-video memory error.
>  1. Reseat DIMMs. Power on the
>   system.
>   2. Replace DIMMs one at a time to isolate the faulty module.
>   3. Replace third-party memory with HP memory.
>   4. Replace the system board.

> Power LED flashes Red five times, once every second, followed by a two
>   second pause, and the computer beeps five times. (Beeps stop after
>   fifth iteration but LEDs continue flashing.) Cause Solution Memory is
>   installed incorrectly or is bad. CAUTION: To avoid damage to the DIMMs
>   or the system board, you must unplug the computer power cord before
>   attempting to reseat, install, or remove a DIMM module.
>   1. Reseat DIMMs. Power on the system.
>   2. Replace DIMMs one at a time to isolate the faulty module.
>   3. Replace third-party memory with HP memory.
>   4. Replace the system board.

Answer (score 0):

As per this manual http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02222922 
5 short beeps - BIOS recovery successful.
You should reset BIOS using jumpuper or pull off the 3V battery for a minute.